# Is there a way to force tab unmount in ChakraUI tabs component?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I tried lazyBehavior="unmount" (which is the default).
Anyway, it doesn't getting unmounted when tab changes..

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-hugle-jqezs?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are additionally missing:

```
isLazy={true}
```

Docs for the `lazyBehavior` prop say:

> The lazy behavior of tab panels' content when not active. Only works
> when `isLazy={true}`

Comment: isLazy just make the unselected panel unmounted initially, but once it is selected, it will stay in dom even it is unselected.

Comment: @Ron I don't get your comment, when you use `isLazy` with `lazyBehavior`, every time you switch from tab1 in the OPs example, you can see message "one destroyed" which means the component was unmounted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, after I added `isLazy`, it will be unmounted after unselected. Updated source: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-turing-lychqg?file=/src/App.tsx